# How to solve for importance in R

Tags: r, random-forest

When I typed the command for importance as below importance (`model.rf`) I get this error:

> Error in UseMethod("importance") : no applicable method for 'importance' applied to an object of class "c('randomForest.formula', 'randomForest')"

How to solve this error?

Comment: Did you try restarting your R session? It's possible you're masking the randomForest `importance()`. Try `randomForest::importance(model.rf)`

Comment: You need to provide a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can see what you are really doing and what objects are involved.

Answer (score 0):

```
output.forest <- randomForest(nativeSpeaker ~ age + shoeSize + score,  data = 
readingSkills,importance=TRUE)
#You can use like this - Solution
out.importance <- round(importance(output.forest), 2)
print(out.importance )
```

first convert importance to variable and then print that out.